# Are there any good Silverlight/HTML file-upload with metadata libraries?

Tags: javascript, html, silverlight, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I need to creating a solution in SharePoint 2010 to upload multiple documents and tag them with metadata.

Does anyone know of an interesting/compelling file-upload control or solution that supports adding metadata to the files?  The solution could be in Silverlight or HTML/Javascript.

I've looked at the [Silverlight Multi file uploader codexplex project](http://slfileupload.codeplex.com/).  It seems pretty powerful, but it doesn't support any concept of tagging of documents.  We could extend the control to add metadata tagging to the documents, but I'd like to hear what others in the community have done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing up this tumbleweed question:  We ended up using the built-in UI in SharePoint.  The users found it easy enough to use.

Answer (score 1):

I used the [telerik silverlight](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/) upload control for this.  It worked quite well.